# How can we search a line of text from a .txt file?

Tags: android, kotlin, full-text-search, linkedin-api, txt

I am working on a project where I have a [skills.txt](https://github.com/varadchoudhari/LinkedIn-Skills-Crawler/blob/master/output/all_skills.txt) file. Now I have to make a `SearchView` to search skills by input in real-time. I don't know how we do this. So I searched for it and find some ways like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55182579/14617810).

But I'm not sure how to use it with a search view to get the desired result like this [source: LinkedIn]

[image]

Comment: You could split the lines and filter the chars onTextChange

Answer (score 0):

In Your Activity onCreationOptionsMenu write this.

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {

    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
    val search = menu.findItem(R.id.search)
    val searchView = search.actionView as androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(object : 
    androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
        override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
            if (query != null && query.isNotEmpty()) {
                viewModel.searchResult(query)
            }
            return false
        }

        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    })
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)}
```

In your view Model write this. Once

```
 private val _searchResultData = SafeMediatorLiveData(initialValue = SearchResultResponse(emptyList()))

fun searchResult(skillSetToSearch: String) {
     // val arrayList = callFiletoSearchString(skillSetToSearch)
    _searchResultData.update(searchListResponse = arrayList)

 }
```

SafeMediatorLive Data class will look like this

```
class SafeMediatorLiveData<T : Any>(initialValue: T) : MediatorLiveData<T>() {

    init {
        value = initialValue
    }

    override fun getValue(): T = super.getValue()!!
}
```